# Script works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a script that works just fine in chrome but not in Firefox and I have no idea why this is. The script is suppose to scroll down to an id from an anchor but does nothing in Firefox.

Example how I use the script below!

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="scroll" target="home">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home">
.....
</div>

<script>
  $('.scroll').click(function() {
  $(document).animate({
  scrollTop: eval($('#' + $(this).attr('target')).offset().top - 70)
  }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: do you get an error in firebug?

Comment: what the heck is that eval for?

Comment: Your `eval` statement is completely unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined` in Chrome for the code when using `$(document).animate` - @Blazemonger is entirely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `$(document).animate` to `$('html,body').animate`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vL79H/

---

That said, I would tighten up your code a bit by using HTML-standard hash links, in case JavaScript is disabled or not working:

```
<li><a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

Then modify the code to accommodate it and remove the unnecessary `eval` statement:

```
$('.scroll').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 70
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4FQn7/